# Add overlay pointer to an popup window in Extjs 4?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I want to add arrow mark to extjs window as marked below. I have created window with all the required form fields and i can point out the place where the user clicked. Now my requirement is to add arrow to that window.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Cool! I have a keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="overlay"> Hello World </div>

#overlay {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: green;
}
#overlay:after  {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 10px solid green;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

The div after overlay is looking like this. In the same way we can add overlay for sencha extjs window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are `.x` and `.y` properties of `Window`. They exist for absolute positioning. You should get mouse pointer's coordinates and then calculate window's position.